# ZeroMQ (via pyzmq) vs. Python Standard Library: Why one over the other?

Tags: python, network-programming, zeromq, pyzmq

Soon I'm going to be writing some Python code to make two services (A and B) talk to each other.  They might be on the same machine, or they might not (but I will know in advance of deployment).  I have two options; either [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html), or [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org) (via [pyzmq](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io)).  **Why would I use one over the other?**

Comment: pyzmq is Python binding for zmq, meaning it allows user to access zmq library using Python.

Comment: I understand that.

Comment: I will use zeromq or its newer reincarnation: nanomsg. These two libraries hide a lot of details from the developer, so that the program is easy to write and very readable. Python's signal implementation in Windows need improvement. However, if you need to write low-level operation that maximize performance (e.g., using mmap) then you should use the standard library.

Comment: Interesting...I will look into nanomsg and nng.  However, I will leave this question unchanged.  Presumably once I have a good comparison between ZeroMQ and standard networking libraries, I will be informed enough to decide between ZeroMQ, nanomsg, and nng.  And if not, I'll ask another question.

Comment: If your messaging follows one of the supported patterns of ZMQ (e.g. PUB-SUB), it may be more convenient to let it take care of the details for you. I have used this successfully as my IPC on a system with many processes collaborating. It has the added benefit that if I publish on a TCP socket, I can use a ZMQ subscriber on another system to see the data. I also like that it reconnects gracefully and has a built-in socket option for heartbeats if you use one of the more recent ZMQ releases.